# conda update spyder fails. Package is not installed in prefix

Tags: macos, anaconda, spyder

I am running Spyder 3.2.4 in Anaconda. I cannot update via the Anaconda Navigator (update options are greyed out, non-selectable.)

I followed the instructions I see when I start Spyder. At the MacOS X command line I run the following commands with the fatal error you can see.

Now what do I do?  I also tried 
StevesiMac2017 
steve@StevesiMac2017: conda update qt pyqt
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

StevesiMac2017 
steve@StevesiMac2017: conda update spyder

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /Users/steve/miniconda3
  package name: spyder

StevesiMac2017 
steve@StevesiMac2017: conda update qt pyqt
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

StevesiMac2017 
steve@StevesiMac2017: conda update spyder

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /Users/steve/miniconda3
  package name: spyder

StevesiMac2017 
steve@StevesiMac2017: conda update --all
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

Comment: As I said yesterday, it seems you have *two* Anaconda installations: one where Spyder is being installed but not updated and the other where it's not even installed. I say it because if you look at the error you're getting above, it clearly says: *Package is not installed in prefix*.

Comment: So you need to find a way to solve this problem in your side. I think the easiest solution is to uninstall one of your two installations and continue installing packages on the other one.

Comment: You are right that I have 2 different Anaconda installations.  I need to clean that up.   In the meantime, I was able to update Spyder using Anaconda Navigator.  First I uninstalled 3.2.4. Then I installed 3.2.8 as prompted by Anaconda Navigator. While I was at it, I updated the Navigator as well.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve this problem.